# Render custom video on iPhone frame backdrop

Tags: video, video-editing, iphone-app

I've been trying to find some piece of software that would be able to "render" arbitrary video within an iPhone screen **frame**, for purposes of usage in advertisements, etc. That is, I want to create a video with an iPhone in it, showing the iPhone screen running some app.

For example (this would be one static shot; the software I'm trying to find would create a video):

[image: Rendered]

The goal is to be able to get a video example of an app rendered on a backdrop with an iPhone frame without having to actually record footage of the iPhone running the app by using a physical camera (which reduces quality and stability, etc.).

The software can run on Windows, on Linux or as a webapp.

Comment: If this is going to be video and not just a still, how would you make a believable video of your app in use, if there won't be fingers in the video interacting with your app?

Comment: @benMiller: We have the technology. All it would require so a decent animated 3 model of hand.
(Have you seen CGI these days?)
This is a pretty cool idea

Answer (score 2):

**[After Effect](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_After_Effects)** is a software which allow you to insert a video into another thanks to its **tracking tool**. But it's not its only functionality, After Effect's capabilities goes very much farther than your needs.

You can:

- Get a background video of somebody using an iPhone.
- On this video define some tracking points like the border of the iPhone.
- Get an other video showing your application running.
- Insert this video into the first one considering previously defined tracking points in order to adapt any 3D movement between videos.

I've already used this software to create fake demonstration of reality augmented application, I think that your objective isn't fully different.